# lambda_sum_largest constraint is not DQCP in CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I have a problem to set a constraint in CVXPY using DQCP. From the documentation I understood, that I can have a constraint in the form

```
quasiconvex>=constant
```

So, as every convex function is also a quasiconvex, then I believe that lambda_sum_largest should also be quasiconvex, and when checked with *.is_dqcp()* it is *True*.
But a constraint like

```
(cp.lambda_sum_largest(A,1)>=2.0).is_dqcp()
```

is not. Therefore I am surprised, what am I missing here?

The full (yet tiny) code is here:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

lambdas = [-2.0,-1.0,1.0,2.0]

x = cp.Variable(4)
A = cp.bmat( np.diag([x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]]) )

constraints  = [cp.lambda_sum_largest(A,1)>=lambdas[-1]]
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(x)), constraints)

problem.solve(qcp=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, an embarassing mistake, the allowed constraint is not

```
quasiconvex>=constant
```

but

```
quasiconvex<=constant
```